# Is it possible to use a Belgian Lycamobile sim-card in Germany?

Tags: germany, cellphones, belgium

I bought a Lycamobile sim-card here in Antwerp and we are leaving tomorrow to go to Germany, Can I still use the sim-card there? And if so, how to reactivate it? What to change in settings?

Comment: As far as I know it will work and no settings are required, this is my personal experience and I have no evidence to support that.

Comment: If it goes into roaming, it will send you the right settings automatically. Expect phone to work, and internet to take a few minutes.

Answer (score 5):

- Yes, it's possible to continue using the same sim-card
- There's no need to "reactivate" or change anything in the settings, it's all automatic
- Note that you won't be able to use the same plan in Germany, however the charges would be capped by EU legislation at a [reasonable level](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-single-market/en/roaming-tariffs). Again, no need to change or do anything, it's all automatic.

However the best solution is to simply buy a local card in Germany. This may change in 2017 when all roaming fees are banned within the EU, but for now it's still better to shop around.

Comment: See [my answer here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/55944/6792) on a bit more details about buying various prepaid SIMs in Germany, especially for heavy data users.